# How to save text same as text area using ASP.Net and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a text area, it has a multiline same as Stackoverflow text area.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserInformation" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

I am using asp.net and SQL Server.

**For example** : `txtUserInformation`contains text like below

```
Hello sir,

     My name is John, from Sydney. I am trying to contact you for so long 
time. But I did n't get an opportunity to meet you. Please give me an appointment.

     1. My name is John, from Sydney. 

     2. I am trying to contact you for so long time. 

     3. But I didn't get an opportunity to meet you. Please give me an appointment.

                             Thank you
```

So now, what datatype can I use to save this text in SQL Server?

And how to save this text area text same as it is? Because I want to display the text on another page.

Comment: VARCHAR or NVARCHAR most likely. Use the latter if you ever expect any unicode characters. The formatting should not cause an issue.

Comment: You dont need do anything, on sql server varchar will store the new lines because are just ansi char `CHAR(13)` to be accurate

Comment: @JacobH will it maintain new line?. So I don't need to anything right?

Comment: All the characters (including the spaces, tabs, returns, lines etc) should be preserved. Just make sure you choose the right size and type. Probably nvarchar(max) as it appears this will have a lot of text data.

Comment: Like so: http://rextester.com/EYPC40694

Comment: Use nvarchar but the DB will be weighter, maybe you can save it in a json object (noSql), and create a rutine for read and write json object, is more efficient